# Visual Studio 2013 won't Hit Break Point - "Source Not Available"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Even with a simple console app I am unable to debug. I get a new tab titled "**Source Not Available**" the shows "**Code not running**" and "**The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be be obtained.**"

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bob"); //break point here
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same results if I try a WinForms application.

I am running:

Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

on Windows 8.1 x64.

I have tried:

- Clean and rebuild.
- Reset all options.
- Repair VS installation.
- Uninstall/Reinstall VS.

Of works fine a old win 7 machine.

Add: Debug/Windows/Threads:

```
Not Flagged     0   0   Unknown Thread  [Thread Destroyed]      
Not Flagged     5864    0   Worker Thread   <No Name>       Normal
Not Flagged     3736    3   Worker Thread   <No Name>       Normal
Not Flagged     3552    7   Worker Thread   vshost.RunParkingWindow     Normal
Not Flagged     5508    0   Worker Thread   <No Name>       Normal
Not Flagged     2448    8   Worker Thread   .NET SystemEvents       Normal
Not Flagged >   3612    9   Main Thread Main Thread     Normal
```

Today I found an [issue on connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807977/code-not-running-the-current-thread-is-not-currently-running-or-the-call-stack-could-not-be-obtained) reporting the same problem/symptoms, but it was closed without resolution when the OP did not respond.

Comment: Did it just stop working or has it never worked on this machine?

Comment: It has worked previously on this machine, but not in this exact configuration. I've recently run some updates, etc. I had hoped that the refreshed install would clear it up.

Comment: Mmmm... have you tried opening VS as Admin? I know it sounds silly, just something that happens on VS 2012 when debugging my ASP.Net IISPOOLs.

Comment: What do you see in the threads & processes window?

Comment: Running as Admin not silly--good test, but didn't help. @SLaks: can you clarify which window/how to get to it? Not immediately obvious that I have one called that.

Comment: @SLaks: Got it. No GPO threads. CPU thread info added to question.

Comment: What do you see in the call stack window?  Does your EXE have symbols loaded in the Modules window?

Comment: @SLaks: Call Stack is empty. Modules windows shows Symbols loaded for my user code and skipped for all the optimized systems stuff. The oddball is:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll No No Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: If the code starts up in the debugger, but skips all statements and break points, it sounds like the config has changed for the debug code type. I know when you ATTACH the debugger, you see these settings, and occasionally, the "Automatic detect" gets it wrong. If this is what is happening, the debugger is running just fine. The problem thinks you are interested in debugging a type of code that isn't what you are interested in (ie, it wants to only debug Native, and you are wanting to debug Managed).

Comment: Check here in VS2013: Tools|Options menu item. Select Debugging node, Just-In-Time sub-node. Look to the right window, and make sure that the following options are checked: Managed, Native

Comment: @StarPilot: I don't have that sub node. Under Debugging I have General, Edit and Continue, Output Window, and Symbols.

Comment: As far as I understand it debugs but does not show call stacks. maybe you want to change the title.

Comment: @ThomasW.Well, it doesn't show the call stack, but primarily it doesn't stop at a break point and I don't get any console output. It just sits there with an empty console and the weird pain. I am happy to clarify the title, but I'm not sure the call stack is the root.